# Сохранение файла с новым именем JS

Tags: javascript

Есть текстовый файл *file.txt* в котором забиты следующие значения в 1 и 2 строчке *"Привет, пока"*. Задача заключается следующая открыть данный файл выбрать например 1 строчку и сохранить новый файл под название *"Привет.txt"*. Соответственно если в файле *file.txt* будут записаны слова "Как дела, плохо" то название нового файла будет *"Как дела.txt"*. Подскажите как реализовать данной код при помощи JS?

Comment: Браузер, командная строка или nodejs? Вашт попытки есть?

Comment: Для реализации данной задачи в JavaScript вы можете использовать Node.js, чтобы работать с файлами.